# ParametricNDSolve and ProcessEquations

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a question regarding NDSolve`ProcessEquations and ParametricNDSolve.

When using the regular NDSolve we have the option to divide the integration into the three steps ProcessEquations, Iterate and ProcessSolutions. My question is: When using ParametricNDSolve, is the ProcessEquation stage only done one time (when we create the ParametricFunction) or is it done every time we call the object with new parameter values?

/Jacob

Comment: Did You try to do some timings?